# EventListenner does not work after replacing innerHTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js

I'm writing a test tool. In my tool, I have a menu which displays all testsuite in the database. When user clicks on a testsuite name, it will display testsuite's content. At first, I add `eventlistenner` to every `submenu`. But every time user import or delete testsuite, I have to update the menu, and add new `eventlistenner` to the new `submenu`. I use jade to generate a HTML code and replace the old menu content with this new one. But the problem is the new `eventlistenner` does not attached to the new sub menu. When I click on the `submenu`, nothing happen. So please tell me what happened and what I have to do?

This is my jade code at first:

```
li(id="RunTestsuite")
                a Run Testsuite
                ul
                    each testsuite in list.listTS
                        li(id="#{testsuite.ID}"): a #{testsuite.ID} - #{testsuite.Name}
                        script.
                            $("#RunTestsuite li##{testsuite.ID}").on("click", function(){
                                socket.emit("open testsuite", "#{testsuite.ID}", true);
                            });
```

This is what I will replace the innerHTML of #RunTestsuite if DB has any update:

```
each testsuite in list
   li(id="#{testsuite.ID}"): a #{testsuite.ID} - #{testsuite.Name}
each testsuite in list
   script.
      window.onload(function(){
         $("##{type} li##{testsuite.ID}").off();
         $("##{type} li##{testsuite.ID}").on("click", function(){
            socket.emit("#{command}", "#{testsuite.ID}");
      });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

On dynamically generated elements is better bind the event listener to an outer element or `body`, like

```
$("body").on("click", "#RunTestsuite li##{testsuite.ID}", function(){
    socket.emit("open testsuite", "#{testsuite.ID}", true);
});
```

and

```
//$("##{type} li##{testsuite.ID}").off();
$("body").on("click", "##{type} li##{testsuite.ID}", function(){
    socket.emit("#{command}", "#{testsuite.ID}");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

By modifying an element using the `.innerHTML` parameter, you basically re-write the HTML to the page, breaking all event listeners. If you are changing an element with an event listener, you will need to re-bind that event listener after modifying the element. However, you can often modify elements without breaking the event listeners attached to it:

- Adding a sub-element: [`.appendChild`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp)
- Adding a neighbor element [`.insertBefore`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_insertbefore.asp)
- Removing a sub-element: [`.removeChild`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_removechild.asp)
- Replacing a sub-element: [`.replaceChild`](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/met_node_replacechild.asp) (breaks event listeners)